# Rotate quadratic function f(x) θ degrees about point P in a one-liner equation

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

Given angle `θ`, point `P`, and function `f(x) = -(x - P.x)^2 + P.y` (a downward quadratic function whose global maximum intercects with `P`), how can I create a new function, `g(x)`, that is `f(x)` rotated `θ` degrees about point `P`?

I am from a computer science background and am trying to program this in Desmos so that I can transcribe it into code, so practical, rather than theoretical, explanations as to how I could go about doing this (preferably as one equation in the form `g(x) = ...`) would be much appreciated.

*If you would like, you can see my progress so far in Desmos here, where the starting function is z(x) and the (failed) rotated function is j(x), where the rotated function should be symmetrical when reflected across line g(x): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qpzqdtou5z*

Here is what I would like it to look like: [image]

Comment: The relation $g$ will not be a function for any non-trivial $\theta$ (i.e. not $180^\circ$ or $0^\circ$); $g$ will fail the vertical line test at $x = P.x.$ Is it necessary that it be a function from $x$ to $y$ for your purpose?

Comment: Not sure whether group theory (tag) assist here.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza I am sorry, I worded that poorly.  It is totally fine if it fails the vertical line test, meaning it is not necessarily a function—so long as it can be plotted as g(x) it will succeed in its purpose, since using code I can return when g(x) returns multiple outputs pretty easily.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'function' is actually a parabola with vertex $P$, and its Cartesian equataion is

$ y = - (x - P_x)^2 + P_y $

Re-arranging the terms of the equation above, we arrive at:

$ (x - P_x)^2 + (y - P_y) = 0 \hspace{15pt}(*) $

The image of the point $(x, y)$ under a rotation by $\theta$ about $P$ is
the point $(x', y')$, where

$ x' = P_x + \cos \theta (x - P_x) - \sin \theta (y - P_y) $

$ y' = P_y + \sin \theta (x - P_x) + \cos \theta (y - P_y) $

Solving for $(x, y)$ in terms of $(x', y')$ we get

$ x = P_x + \cos \theta (x' - P_x) + \sin \theta (y' - P_y) $

$ y = P_y - \sin \theta (x' - P_x) + \cos \theta (y' - P_y) $

Using these two equations in the equation of the original parabola given by equation $(*)$, we arrive at:

$ ( \cos \theta (x' - P_x) + \sin \theta (y' - P_y) )^2 + ( - \sin \theta (x' - P_x) + \cos \theta (y' - P_y) ) = 0 $

And this is the one-liner equation that is required.  You can remove the primes above the primed variables, i.e. replace $(x', y')$ with $(x, y)$, to obtain

$ ( \cos \theta (x - P_x) + \sin \theta (y - P_y) )^2 + ( - \sin \theta (x - P_x) + \cos \theta (y - P_y) ) = 0 $

Comment: This [worked perfectly](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/czabt6zlmr), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure of what you mean by "*rotating a function about point* `P` ".
But since you come from computer science, I'm assuming you are doing some simulation of a trajectory (sorry if I'm assuming wrong, I come from physics... maybe that's why) and thus that you want to "*rotate the picture of the trajectory*".

You will not be able to do this using a simple `g(x)` function... Mathematically speaking this is because your function is not a *bijection* of $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ or graphically:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iDEM.png)

If you turn your curve "too much" it no longer represent a *function* of `x` because to a single value of `x` you are now giving `2` or `0` values `f(x)`...

Then, there are many ways to do things, (parametric equations, restriction of your function to a subset where is is a bijection ($\mathbb{R}_+$), rotating your axis afterward...)
But they all depend on precisely what it is you want to do, and since I've been making a lot of assumptions on what it is you truly want to do, I think I'd better leave it here...

Comment: Hi there—I have done trajectory simulations.  You are right that it is not technically a function in case it is rotated non-trivially.  It is totally fine if it fails the vertical line test—I can simply program my function to return multiple outputs when necessary.  As long as g(x) represents the function like so: [image](https://imgur.com/PwseBm0).

Comment: Then I you are trully doing trajectories (and you have nothing preventing it) I think the best solution is to first compute the trajectory as you would normally (i.e. `theta=0`) and only after that is done, rotate the output coordinate (like you rotate a regular vector...)
All set? (If this is not clear, I can give you the equations)

Comment: I have unfortunately yet to take linear algebra (I'm taking it next semester), so if you could provide me the equations or a place I could look to find the equations, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thank you very much for your help so far.